Probability of Sum of i.i.d random variables being positive
Let $g,l \in (0,1)$ and $p\in [0,1].$ Let the distribution of random variable $Z_1$ be as follows:
$ Z_1 = g+l$ with probability $(1-p)p,$ $Z_1 = g$ with probability $(1-p)^2,$ $Z_1 = l-1$ with probability $p^2$ and $Z_1 = -1$ with probability $p(1-p).$
$Z_1, Z_2, \dots, Z_k$ are i.i.d random variables.
Let $Z= Z_1+Z_2+\dots+Z_k$ and $f(p) = Pr(Z>0).$
Can we say that the function $f(p)$ is strictly decreasing in $p?$
Numerical evidence kind of suggests that the above statement is true. However, I would like to see an analytical proof of this. Any help (with either proving/disproving the above conjecture) would be greatly appreciated.
I started by computing $E[Z_1].$ One can show that $E[Z_1] = -(1+g-l)p +g$ which is clearly decreasing in $p.$ I was trying to use this fact about $E[Z_1]$ to prove the statement about $Pr(Z>0)$ but without much success so far.
